# IPhone development-- how to get bookmarks and history data from UIWebView?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

As the description of title, Which interface of UIWebView should I call to get these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the current API. You will have to maintain state i.e. track bookmarks and history data but that too from user's usage of your `UIWebView` instance. You can't get the data of Mobile Safari. Although `UIWebView` instance allows you to navigate back and forth indicating that it does maintain some sort of state, all of it is cloaked inside the `UIWebViewInternal` class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to maintain your own history is to implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

When the navigation type is UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked you can add it to your own history array.